# How do you click a calendar and copy the date to a textbox without postback, in asp.net with javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, calendar, postback

I have a asp.net page that is used for searching rows of data. I want to be able to search a specific date-interval, therefore I have added two calendars (from & to) and a textbox for each one.

When a date is selected in the calendar it is displayed in the matching textbox, although this causes a postback, and that is my problem.

I have never used javascript before, so I thought I would give that a go, but I almost exclusivly see examples using HTML, which I am not using at all. I only use ASP.NET web controls such as `<asp:Calendar.../>`.

So this code that follows is just off the top of my head, I know the javascript is totally wrong, but I hope you understand what it is that I want to achieve when you look at it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Calendar1_SelectionChanged() {
        FromDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
    }
</script>    

<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
    onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>

<asp:TextBox ID="FromDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

All answers are greatly appreciated! I have been trying to find an answer to this by googling, but no luck..

EDIT: For this to work on the page, I need to keep the textboxes. Or any other way where the date can be edited manually (in DateTime format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that when the page is actually served to the browser, it's altered from what exactly you have posted there. The `onselectionchanged` event is not a javascript event, it does the postback to call the method `Calendar1_SelectionChanged` back at the server. Your javascript code, although the function appears to have the same name as the `onselectionchanged` event, is not being run.

My recommendation is to use a [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

I'm also not sure your javascript is exactly what it should be to work as you expect it to. It looks like you're using a few C# properties/methods...

Comment: okay so I checked the datepicker out and it looks really awesome, but the thing is that I use those textboxes for input from a dropdownlist and manual input as well, the jquery datepicker does not seem to support that. This is only for an admin interface so it doesn't have to be fancy. Thanks for the help nonetheless, I will definitely be using the datepicker in the future.

Comment: You should still be able to set the value of the textbox using the datepicker. Whether it be set by hand or by a drop down list. Let me look into that real quick.

Comment: The datepicker allows you to type in a date if in the proper format. You won't be able to type in "January 12, 2011" but you could type in "01/12/2011" and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the help Corey, it looks like datepicker can be a good addition to what I'm working on. I'm listing this as an answer seeing as there was no way to do Exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the jQuery calendars instead of the asp ones personally. This would definitely avoid any postbacks. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/